# Tell a PHP Class to always run it's constructor when it is extended

Tags: php, class, constructor, extend

From what I understand, when a PHP Class is extended, it's constructor is not called? So in the below, the method `Options_Page_Template->on_enqueue_scripts()` is never actually run -

```
class Options_Page_Template{

    function __construct(){ 

        /** Enqueue scrips and styles for use in this plugin */
        add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', array(&$this, 'on_enqueue_scripts'));

    }

    function on_enqueue_scripts(){

        { do Whatever here }

    }

}

class Options_Home extends Options_Page_Template{

    function __construct(){ 

        { Add various actions here }

    }


}
```

Is there a way of telling `Options_Page_Template()` to always run it's own `__constructor()` when it is extended? I know I can use `parent::__construct()`, but that involves adding the code to all the files that extend the Class.

I also tried the the old-school method of giving the constructor the same name as the Class, but PHP is obviously more clever than that, as it did not work. Thanks.

Comment: Short answer: No. If the child class overloads the constructor, it *must* call `parent::__construct()` in order for the parent constructor to run. End of story.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must always use `parent::__construct()` if you are createing a __construct in both classes You do have an option to turn it around. You could have your parent class constructor check for the existence of a custom constructor in the child and run it.

```
<?php
class Options_Page_Template{
    function __construct(){ 
        if (method_exists($this,'__beforeconstruct'))
          $this->__beforeconstruct();

        echo "construct class<br/>";

        if (method_exists($this,'__afterconstruct'))
          $this->__afterconstruct();

    }

    function on_enqueue_scripts(){
    }
}

class Options_Home extends Options_Page_Template{
    function __beforeconstruct(){ 
       echo "Extended class before<br/>";
    }

    function __afterconstruct(){ 
       echo "Extended class after<br/>";
    }
}

new Options_Home();

?>
```

output:

```
Extended class before
construct class
Extended class after
```

Comment: That's actually a pretty neat way of doing it. Tested and working, and should achieve what I want. Thanks muchly.

Answer (score 5):

There's no way. A good rule of thumb for all your code, is to always call parent::__construct for every subclass that overrides the constructor; and explicitly comment within the constructor if you are not, and why.

In general, for functions and con/destructors, if you override something; you are also responsible for calling the parent function.

Comment: As I thought, but that is a bit of a shame. Perhaps it's something for a future version. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: No. This would violate one basic idea behind object oriented programming: Every class is responsible to care for its internal correctness. If I could enforce the usage of the base constructor I would take things out of the hand of the inherited class. I this class does not want to call the parent's constructor then it has to handle things on its own.

Comment: @ChristophGrimmer-Dietrich: limited space here, but while I generally agree 100% for methods, I think the constructor is a bit of a weird one. For one, PHP does not enforce the constructor signature when subclassing. Second: if a parent class is from a different package, but the constructor body changes.. this is not an API change. Trying to always a parent constructor just 'as a habit' _unless_ there's a good reason not to, helps with robustness imho.

Comment: @Evert There is a bit of a misunderstanding here. I responded to David and wholeheartedly support your answer. Of course one should always call the overridden method, constructor or not, unless there is a very good reason not to.

Answer (score 2):

You could do something nasty like define your constructor as final and have a protected init method which extended classes can override but I wouldn't recommend it to be honest.

This way if someone tries to write a constructor in a child class they'll get something like:

PHP Fatal error:  Cannot override final method A::__construct() in php shell code on line 5

You probably need to look at a different approach to the way you've organised your classes instead.

Comment: Thanks @Jason, I'm thinking the same also (looking at the organisation).

Comment: Putting "final" on the constructor is indeed a nasty thing to do. However, I've seen what you propose multiple times in larger components that expect a lot of subclasses that need to implement custom construction logic. If you run into such problems often consider it an issue in your object design. Otherwise, there is nothing wrong with implementing a blank and protected "init()" method that gets called in the constructor.

Comment: Thanks @Niko. I think your `init()` suggestion is essentially what @HugoDelsing suggested in his answer, which is the way I will probably go.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Options_Home extends Options_Page_Template{

    function __construct() { 
       parent::__construct(); // Needs to be first line so the rest of the constructor
                              // can assume the Options_Page_Template has been constructed.
       // Various stuff here for Options_home constructor

    }


}
```

Should work.

Answer (score -2):

Just don't define a constructor the for the extending class.

Comment: Sadly that is not an option, as I need to hook various actions when the page loads.

Comment: Then you would need to call `parent::__construct();` in each constructor